# How to highlight all instances of a string using Chrome's Text Fragments feature?

Tags: google-chrome

I recently found out about the new Chrome feature called "Text Fragments" that allows links to point directly to a certain text inside an URL and have it highlighted.  For example:

[https://www.nytimes.com/#:~:text=Magazine](https://www.nytimes.com/#:%7E:text=Magazine)

But if I point to a work that appears multiple times, only the first instance gets highlighted.

Is there any way that I can ask it to highlight all occurrences of a given string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, the spec only allows for highlighting the first instance found on a page.  You can specify multiple strings, but they'll all always match to the first occurrence (as of Chrome 83).

The best I can think of is expanding the matching region such that each occurrence is a unique substring.  For instance, on this page one could use something like:

```
#:~:text=highlight%20all&text=highlighted&text=it%20to%20highlight&text=for%20highlighting
```

And generate these URLs via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I found a website where a syntax like `[URL]?s[]=MySearchTerm&s[]=MyOtherSearchTerm` works:

[https://www.ipwiki.de/arbeitnehmererfinderrecht:beschraenkte_inanspruchnahme?s[]=inanspruchnahme&s[]=Arbeitgeber&s[]=Diensterfindung](https://www.ipwiki.de/arbeitnehmererfinderrecht:beschraenkte_inanspruchnahme?s%5B%5D=inanspruchnahme&s%5B%5D=Arbeitgeber&s%5B%5D=Diensterfindung)

However, this syntax doesn't seem to work anywhere else, so it's probably not a feature of Chrome but a function of that website.